# Confused as to how the template render action is called

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor, meteorite

I am trying to make the songs in a playlist appear on screen each time a user enters a song of choice. I have the following action to insert the song that they chose into the database:

```
 Template.search_bar.events({
'keypress #query' : function (evt,template) {
  // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (evt.which === 13){
            var url = template.find('#query').value;
            $("#query").val('');
            $('#playlist_container').animate({scrollTop: $('#playlist_container')[0].scrollHeight});
            Template.list.search_get(url,0);    //insert records into the database
        }
   }

});
```

**Template.list.search_get** inserts the record into the database:

```
Meteor.call('update_record',Template.list.my_playlist_id, song, function(err,message){});
```

on the server side, I am pushing records into my database with the following format:

```
update_record: function(sessID, songObj){
    Links.update({sess: sessID}, {$push: {songs: {song_title: songObj["title"], videoId: songObj["video_id"], thumbnail: songObj["thumbnail"], index: songObj["index"]}}});
},
```

basically all my records have the format of:

```
{_id:,
 sess:, 
 songs: [{song_title:,
          videoId:,
          thumbnail:,
          index:},
         {song_title:,
          videoId:,
          thumbnail:,
          index:},...]
}
```

An array of song objects inside the songs field of the record. What I am trying to do is each time a user hits the search button, make that new song appear in the list. **I am not sure how many times the render function gets called or how template renders a database object in hmtl**. Currently i have the following html template for my list:

```
<template name="list">
<div id="playlist_container">
  <ul id="playlist">
    {{#each my_playlist.songs}}
           {{> track}}
    {{/each}}   
 </ul>
</div>
```

I believe **my_playlist** should call the following action on the client:

```
  Template.list.my_playlist = function(){
    console.log("myplaylist is called");
    return Links.findOne({sess: Template.list.my_playlist_id});
  }
```

It should return an object which contains an array of song object, for which i iterate through in **#each my_playlist.songs**, which should render each of the following track template:

```
<template name="track">
<li id="{{index}}" class="list_element">
    <div class="destroy"> </div>
    <div class="element_style">{{song_title}}</div>
</li>
</template>
```

However, upon successful insertion of record, i am not seeing the new song title appear. Any suggestions on how I might approach this?

Comment: How is `Template.list.my_playlist_id` set? Are you sure that value is actually changing?

Comment: I set my_playlist_id on meteor.starup(), and i subscribe using the playlist_id right after I set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is the problem.

```
Template.list.my_playlist = function(){
    return Links.findOne({sess: Template.list.my_playlist_id});
}
```

`Template.list.my_playlist_id` never updates, and thus, the new template never renders.

Try this approach.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        update_record: function(sessID, songObj){
            // update Links
            return Links.findOne({sess: sessID});
        }
    });
} else {
   Meteor.call('update_record',Template.list.my_playlist_id, song, function(err, song){
        Session.set('playlist', song);
    });
    Template.list.my_playlist = function(){
        return Session.get('playlist');
    }
}
```

Comment: should i still put the code for Links.update inside the update_record? What causes the new template to render?

Comment: @mlikj2006 Yes, and the new template is rendered whenever `Session` changes because `Session` is a reactive data source.

Comment: Lemme see if i can get this straight, so the jist of the solution is, whenever i call the server from the client side to update the record, after update i pass the song object back to the client (to make sure it was properly added to the database). I then take the song object on the client side and i append it to a session variable. my_playlist then grabs the new session variable and that would force the template to re-render. That means that my_playlist function is called every time i hit enter to add a song?

Comment: `my_playlist` function isn't executed each time(not 100% sure on that). Since `Session` is a reactive data source, Meteor is automagically syncing `Template.list.my_playlist` to the value of `Session.get('playlist');`